# how can I import several .txt files into r using loops for text analysis

Tags: r, loops

I'm working on a bibliometric analysis in r that requires me to work with data obtained from the Web of Science database. I import my data into r using the following code:

```
file1 <- "data1.txt"
data1 <- convert2df(file = file1, dbsource = "isi", format = "plaintext")
```

I have about 35 text files that I need to repeat this code for. I would like to do so using loops, something I don't have much experience with. I tried something like this but it did not work:

```
list_of_items <- c("file1", "file2")
dataset <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(list_of_items))

for (i in list_of_items){
  dataset[i] <- convert2df(file = list_of_items[i], dbsource = "isi", format = "plaintext")
  print(dataset)}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument
```

I'm not very familiar with using loops but I need to finish this work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: May you share a peak into your text file?

Comment: It's hard to tell with no example, but you can try 
file = paste(list_of_items[i])
It seems you have a problem with your file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R wants to open `file1`, but you only have `file1.txt`. The filenames in the list are incorrect.

I once had that problem as well, maybe the solution works for you too.

maybe put all text files in a folder and read the folder, this might be easier.

```
FOLDER_PATH <- #your path here just paste it from the explorer bar (Windows). Beware to replace`\` with `\\`


file_paths <- list.files(path = FOLDER_PATH,
                         full.names = TRUE # so you do not change working dir
                         ) # please put only txt in the folder or read the doc on list.files

# using lapply you do not need a for loop, but this is optional
dataset <- lapply(file_paths, convert2df, dbsource = "isi", format = "plaintext")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the problem!